# how transfer the data in link one html to another html by using angularjs

Tags: angularjs

```
<tr ng-repeat="greeting in posts">
    <!--<td>{{greeting.user}}</td>-->

    <td>
        <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
            <a href="quizlist.js">{{greeting.page_name}} </a>
        </div>
    </td> 

    <td>{{greeting.created_by}}</td>
    <td>{{greeting.created_on}}</td>
    <td>{{greeting.modified_by}}</td>
    <td>{{greeting.modified_on}}</td>
</tr>
```

But how to transfer the value of `{{greeting.page_name}}` to another page `(test.html)` using *angularjs*?

Answer (score 0):

fun() is the function in the controller MyCtrl

You can use

```
ng-click=fun(arg)
```

to the element in list, and in that function give arg value to $rootScope.argname, like

```
$rootScope.argname = arg;
```

Now change the state in function fun() using

```
state.go('test');
```

And use $rootScope.argname in the controller of state 'test'.

I've given this answer considering app.js as,

```
state = 'test'
controller = test.js
template = test.html
```

In my case I used a code something like, in template

```
<div id="page-wrapper" class="sides">
                    <h2>User List</h2>
                    <ul ng-repeat="item in items">
                        <li ng-repeat="(key, val) in item">
                            <ul>
                                <li>
                                    <div  ng-click="getUserChat(key)">
                                        <a>{{key}}</a>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
</div>
```

In controller

```
$scope.getUserChat = function(selectedFriend){
    $rootScope.selectedFriend = selectedFriend;
    $rootScope.sentChatMessages = [];
    $state.go('chat.chatbox');
};
```

And used $rootScope.selectedFriend in controller of state 'chat.chatbox'